# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in

Tags: mysqli, php

**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in Z:\home\newmy\www\core\modules\portfolio\portfolio.php on line 17**
Ругается,  в чём проблема? на 17 строке:

> $row =
> $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Вот весь код:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id = ?") or die ("Ошибка #327387239");
$sql->bind_param("i", $id);
$id = $routes[2];
$sql->execute() or die("Предупреждение о неудачном запросе");
$row = $sql->get_result();
if ($row->num_rows){
  $row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo $row['title'];
```

Comment: А fetch_array -- это чей метод? mysqli_stmt -- так ведь нет. mysqli_result -- да. Там что-то было про mysqli_query(), mysqli_store_result() или mysqli_use_result().

А про execute написано:  Если выполняются запросы UPDATE, DELETE, или INSERT, то количество измененных строк можно определить фунцией mysqli_stmt_affected_rows(). Если запрос возвращает результирующий набор, для извлечения данных из него можно использовать функцию mysqli_stmt_fetch().

Может и правда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row = $sql->get_result(); // что тут должно выводиться-то? для чего тут get_result? Убери эту строчку и все. должно помочь.
if ($row->num_rows){
  $row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo $row['title'];
```

Comment: get_result - мы получаем результат из запроса, далее условие есть ли статьи, без той строчки никак!

Comment: Тогда почему `$sql->fetch_array()` а не `$row->fetch_array()` ?

Comment: я сначала делал так, ток вообще ничего не выводит, вот вар_дамп
object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(10) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }

Comment: Да, php -- это диагноз. `get_result` у меня работать не захотел. Попробуйте `$sql->fetch` -- у меня оно заработало. php 5.3.14. Но ему надо `bind_result`

Answer (score 0):

смотрите что у вас содержится в `$sql`. Оно ругается, что `$sql` у ва не объект. Скорее всего какаято ошибка происходит.

Comment: у меня MySQLI 
вот что говорит вар дамп:
object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(10) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }